# Why are null checks bad / why would I want an optional to succeed if it's null?

Tags: swift, kotlin, null, option-type

I've read more than a few answers to similar questions as well as a few tutorials, but none address my main confusion. I'm a native Java coder, but I've programmed in Swift as well.

Why would I ever want to use optionals instead of nulls?

I've read that it's so there are less null checks and errors, but these are necessary or easily avoided with clean programming.

I've also read it's so all references succeed (https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/309137/227611 and `val length = text?.length`). But I'd argue this is a bad thing or a misnomer. If I call the length function, I expect it to contain a length. If it doesn't, the code should deal with it right there, not continue on.

What am I missing?

Comment: I don't know about how it applies to Java/kotlin, but in Swift, if you declare a value as been "optional" it places a greater weight on the developer to make decisions about how to handle those values - like unwrapping them or checking for them, as well as compiler level checks.  Many issues in Java and ObjC come down to "assuming" the state of the value, which causes crashes at runtime.  So, optionals is the languages way of making a developer more aware of the potential risk. Optionals also provide a contract to the outside world, letting people know a value may not be initialised

Comment: @MadProgrammer Valid reasoning, and not trivial. But can't this also be fixed by just being explicit with documentation? IE: If a variable is allowed to be null, it is specified so and when in the documentation. If it's null another time or if you don't handle the null when it's supposed to happen, it's a bug.

Comment: *"explicit with documentation"*  ... sorry, but I've seen too much documentation which contradicts reality.  Through the use of optionals, you are providing "self documenting code".  An API why be deliberately vague on the subject as either the developer didn't think to mention yet (and yes, you see this all the time) or the API is abstract enough as to not know if a value could be null or not.

Comment: "explicit with documentation"   You always want the compiler to do as much work for you as possible.  Humans aren't perfect. We rely on these tools to catch our errors.  And far better to catch them during compile than at runtime (or when we finally get around to reading the docs...).  Isn't an API more useful if you don't have to read the docs to know the contract of the API?  I'm all for solid and detailed docs, but I'm even more for straightforward APIs without hidden gotchas.

Comment: This question does not apply to Kotlin. What Kotlin uses normally is *explicitly* nullable types, *explicitly* non-null types and null safety operators, not optional types. Although the syntaxes of Swift optional types and Kotlin nullable types are very similar, they are inherently different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Optionals provide clarity of type.  An Int stores an actual value - always, whereas an Optional Int (i.e. Int?) stores either the value of an Int or a nil.  This explicit "dual" type, so to speak, allows you to craft a simple function that can clearly declare what it will accept and return.  If your function is to simply accept an actual Int and return an actual Int, then great.

```
func foo(x: Int) -> Int
```

But if your function wants to allow the return value to be nil, and the parameter to be nil, it must do so by explicitly making them optional:

```
func foo(x: Int?) -> Int?
```

In other languages such as Objective-C, objects can always be nil instead. Pointers in C++ can be nil, too.  And so any object you receive in Obj-C or any pointer you receive in C++ ought to be checked for nil, just in case it's not what your code was expecting (a real object or pointer).

In Swift, the point is that you can declare object types that are non-optional, and thus whatever code you hand those objects to don't need to do any checks.  They can just safely just use those objects and know they are non-null.  That's part of the power of Swift optionals. And if you receive an optional, you must explicitly unpack it to its value when you need to access its value. Those who code in Swift try to always make their functions and properties non-optional whenever they can, unless they truly have a reason for making them optional.

The other beautiful thing about Swift optionals is all the built-in language constructs for dealing with optionals to make the code faster to write, cleaner to read, more compact... taking a lot of the hassle out of having to check and unpack an optional and the equivalent of that you'd have to do in other languages.

The nil-coalescing operator (??) is a great example, as are if-let and guard and many others.

In summary, optionals encourage and enforce more explicit type-checking in your code - type-checking that's done by by the compiler rather than at runtime.  Sure you can write "clean" code in any language, but it's just a lot simpler and more automatic to do so in Swift, thanks in big part to its optionals (and its non-optionals too!).

Comment: In Java, all object references are already dual type. Additionally, I still don't get under what circumstance you'd want a function to perform if you give it invalid input. `foo(null)` or `foo({unassigned optional})` _should_ throw an error.

Comment: That they encourage in-code documentation is a logical reason though.

Comment: Right. In Swift I can pass in an object that is *not* optional, is the point.  The receiving code need not check for nil to validate the object.  As for foo(nil), it shouldn't be hard to imagine a method that optionally accepts a parameter... if the caller chooses to pass in nil for the parameter, the method carries on without it.

Comment: Bingo! "Those who code in Swift try to always make their functions and properties non-optional whenever they can, unless they truly have a reason for making them optional." The real benefit of optionals is the ability to declare non-optionals! It's so much easier and safer to code with non-optionals. There are zillions of situations where optionals (variables that can be null) aren't needed. Great answer.

Comment: @MikeTaverne That clears it up a lot actual, thanks. I eventual got that from Smartcat's answer, but it took a few minutes.

Answer (score 0):

1. Avoids error at compile time. So that you don't pass unintentionally nulls.
2. In Java, any variable can be null. So it becomes a ritual to check for null before using it. While in swift, only optional can be null. So you have to check only optional for a possible null value.
3. You don't always have to check an optional. You can work equally well on optionals without unwrapping them. Sending a method to optional with null value does not break the code.

There can be more but those are the ones that help a lot.

Comment: 1) If you're unintentionally passing a null, you _should_ get an error. This is a bug.

Comment: 2) You should assume that a variable isn't null unless there is a valid scenario in which it could be. And in that case you should be checking for a null value. 3) Swift has given me many issues about assuming optionals are not null in functions, etc. Maybe this is just a Swift thing though.

Comment: @Prime624 1)Yes that is a bug in swift but not in other languages. That is why optionals are useful. 2) Well, if I am passing around a variable, I shouldn't bother to check if it is a null but if I am to use it I need to check if it has a valid value. So it seems to be pretty much always the case. 3) It was hard to digest the concept of optionals at the start but the more I started using optionals wisely my apps stoped crashing due unknown reasons which included empty responses from server, wrong JSON format, etc.

Answer (score 0):

**TL/DR:** The null checks that you say can be avoided with clean programming can also be avoided *in a much more rigorous way* by the compiler. And the null checks that you say are necessary can be enforced *in a much more rigorous way* by the compiler. Optionals are the type construct that make that possible.

---

> `var length = text?.length`

This is actually a good example of one way that optionals are useful. If text doesn't have a value, then it can't have a length either. In Objective-C, if `text` is nil, then any message you send it does nothing and returns 0. That fact was sometimes useful and it made it possible to skip a lot of nil checking, but it could also lead to subtle errors.

On the other hand, many other languages point out the fact that you've sent a message to a nil pointer by helpfully crashing immediately when that code executes. That makes it a little easier to pinpoint the problem during development, but run time errors aren't so great when they happen to users.

Swift takes a different approach: if `text` doesn't point to something that has a length, then *there is no length*. An optional isn't a pointer, it's a kind of type that either has a value or doesn't have a value. You might assume that the variable `length` is an `Int`, but it's actually an `Int?`, which is a completely different type.

> If I call the length function, I expect it to contain a length. If it doesn't, the code should deal with it right there, not continue on.

If `text` is nil then there is no object to send the `length` message to, so `length` never even gets called and the result is nil. Sometimes that's fine — it makes sense that if there's no `text`, there can't be a `length` either. You may not care about that — if you were preparing to draw the characters in `text`, then the fact that there's no `length` won't bother you because there's nothing to draw anyway. The optional status of both `text` and `length` forces you to deal with the fact that those variables don't have values at the point where you need the values.

Let's look at a slightly more concrete version:

```
var text : String? = "foo"
var length : Int? = text?.count
```

Here, `text` has a value, so `length` also gets a value, but `length` is still an optional, so at some point in the future you'll have to check that a value exists before you use it.

```
var text : String? = nil
var length : Int? = text?.count
```

In the example above, `text` is nil, so `length` also gets nil. Again, you have to deal with the fact that both `text` and `length` might not have values before you try to use those values.

```
var text : String? = "foo"
var length : Int = text.count
```

Guess what happens here? The compiler says ***Oh no you don't!*** because `text` is an optional, which means that any value you get from it must also be optional. But the code specifies `length` as a non-optional `Int`. Having the compiler point out this mistake at compile time is *so much nicer* than having a user point it out much later.

```
var text : String? = "foo"
var length : Int = text!.count
```

Here, the `!` tells the compiler that you think you know what you're doing. After all, you *just* assigned an actual value to `text`, so it's pretty safe to assume that `text` is not nil. You might write code like this because you want to allow for the fact that `text` might later become nil. Don't force-unwrap optionals if you don't know for certain, because...

```
var text : String? = nil
var length : Int = text!.count
```

...if `text` *is* nil, then you've betrayed the compiler's trust, and you deserve the run time error that you (and your users) get:

```
error: Execution was interrupted, reason: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)
```

Now, if `text` is *not* optional, then life is pretty simple:

```
var text : String = "foo"
var length : Int = text.count
```

In this case, you *know* that `text` and `length` are both safe to use without any checking because they cannot possibly be nil. You don't have to be careful to be "clean" -- you literally can't assign anything that's not a valid `String` to `text`, and every `String` has a `count`, so `length` will get a value.

> Why would I ever want to use optionals instead of nulls?

Back in the old days of Objective-C, we used to manage memory manually. There was a [small number of simple rules](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmRules.html), and if you followed the rules rigorously, then Objective-C's retain counting system worked very well. But even the best of us would occasionally slip up, and sometimes complex situations arose in which it was hard to know exactly what to do. A huge portion of Objective-C questions on StackOverflow and other forums related to the memory management rules. Then Apple introduced ARC (automatic retain counting), in which the compiler took over responsibility for retaining and releasing objects, and memory management became *much* simpler. I'll bet fewer than 1% of Objective-C and Swift questions here on SO relate to memory management now.

**Optionals are like that:** they shift responsibility for keeping track of whether a variable has, doesn't have, or can't possibly not have a value from the programmer to the compiler.